# How can i simplify a pattern rules in makefile?

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

I am newbie in makefile creating.
Can you show me how to simpify my makefile, give some tips?
In my code i have to create a new pattern rule for an every new directory.

```
KERNEL_SRCS = $(wildcard $(KERNEL_DIR)*.c)
KERNEL_HDRS = $(wildcard $(KERNEL_DIR)*.h)

DRIVERS_SRCS = $(wildcard $(DRIVERS_DIR)*.c)
DRIVERS_HDRS = $(wildcard $(DRIVERS_DIR)*.h)

LIBS_SRCS = $(wildcard $(LIBS_DIR)*.c)
LIBS_HDRS = $(wildcard $(LIBS_DIR)*.h)

KERNEL_DIR = src/kernel/
DRIVERS_DIR = src/drivers/
LIBS_DIR = src/libs/
OBJS_DIR = objs/

$(OBJS_DIR)%.o: $(DRIVERS_DIR)%.c $(HDRS)
    gcc -m32 -fno-pie -ffreestanding -c $< -o $@

$(OBJS_DIR)%.o: $(KERNEL_DIR)%.c $(HDRS)
    gcc -m32 -fno-pie -ffreestanding -c $< -o $@

$(OBJS_DIR)%.o: $(LIBS_DIR)%.c $(HDRS)
    gcc -m32 -fno-pie -ffreestanding -c $< -o $@
```

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: It is more conventional to build objects into the same directory as their corresponding sources.  Doing so has several advantages, not least that you don't need a separate rule for each source directory.  In fact, for how you're actually compiling, you could that way do without any explicit %.o:%.c rules at all.

Answer (score 2):

You can [use VPATH](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/General-Search.html):

```
VPATH := $(KERNEL_DIR):$(DRIVERS_DIR):$(LIBS_DIR)

$(OBJS_DIR)%.o: %.c $(HDRS)
        gcc -m32 -fno-pie -ffreestanding -c $< -o $@
```

You should be using a lot more variables,such as `CC` to hold the compiler, `CFLAGS` to hold compiler flags, etc.

There are various other things to consider such as automatic dependency detection, whether or not you can really put all the object files into the same directory or not, etc.